# HTML specified for the submit button, php post prameter not passed

Tags: html

If a class is specified for the submit button, the post method parameter is not passed to php.

```
<form class = "delete_button", action="deleted.php" method="post">

            <select name="nation" size=1>
                <option value="KR">KR</option>
                <option value="JP">JP</option>
                <option value="US">US</option>
                <option value="UK">UK</option>
                <option value="GM">GM</option>
            </select>

            <input name = "email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email">

            <input class="delete_button_content" style="color:white" type="submit" value="delete">

</form>
```

and when I delete class for submit, it's working. what's problem ??

Comment: could you try <form class="delete_button" action="/deleted.php" method="post">

Comment: Try adding an `id` to the button as well as the `class` attribute, and select the button by the `id` in your php.